# преобразовать массив к строке для отправки на сервер

Tags: javascript

при onSubmit на форме отправляются некоторые поля этой формы методом POST. Соответственно их нужно привести к виду типо a=123&b=456&c=789
Поля каждый раз разные. Необходимо написать универсальную функцию, которая имея форму(т.е. все поля) и массив с полями для отправки вернёт строку.

Вызов функции например такой:
serialize(form, ['inn', 'email'])

Вот такая реализация оставляет в конце знак &

```
function serialize(form, dataArr) {
   return dataArr.reduceRight(function(prev, current) {
      return `${current}=${form[current].value}&${prev}`;
   }, "");
```

Comment: Стоит учитывать, что GET имеет ограничение по длине.

Answer (score 0):

Что-то примерно такое ?

```js
let form = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3
};
let arr = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

let a = arr.map(e => `${e}=${form[e]}`).join('&');

console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

У вас `&` лишний, потому что при первой итерации у вас `prev` - пустая строка

```js
const serialize = (form, dataArr) =>
  dataArr.map((field) =>
    `${field}=${form[field].value}`
  ).join('&')


const test = {
  'inn': {
    value: 'inn1341'
  },
  'phone': {
    value: '8984374151'
  },
  'name': {
    value: 'User'
  }
}

console.log(serialize(test, ['phone', 'name', 'inn']))
```